# MongoDB didn't work with NPM. Bug is only on Window, it works correctly with OSX. Module not found: Can't resolve 'dns'

Tags: node.js, database, windows, mongodb

I have installed mongodb with npm (`npm install --save mongodb`) on my project but when I use simple call of mongodb `var mongo = require('mongodb');` or `const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;`
 it displays :

```
./node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/uri_parser.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'dns' in 'C:\Users\fff\Documents\Mes fichiers reçus\MyProjects\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib'
```

I don't hunderstand why it displays this. I tried to install globally mongodb with npm but it hasn't changed.

I looked on my `node_modules\mongodb-core\lib` I have found `uri_parser.js`

It happens only on my windows 7 computeur. With my MacBook, that work correctly.

package.json :

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.0-14",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.1.0-11",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "0.1.0-11",
    "mongodb": "^3.1.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.2.5",
    "react": "^15.6.1",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.31.3",
    "react-dom": "^15.6.1",
    "react-google-auth": "^0.4.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "react-scripts": "1.0.13"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```

Comment: Always refer to official documentation: http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.1/tutorials/connect/

Comment: Thank you but isn't change :/

Comment: Where do you try to use this in your App? Frontend or backend? Also, can we see your `packgage.json` file?

Comment: Frontend app, If you want but like I said, works with macos and dosen't work on windows then I don't think the probleme is from my package.json

Comment: No backend and this works on MacOS?

Comment: Yes I have juste my front app that I have create with react-create-app and in my App.js i have tried to call mongo. And with my OSX it is good, with my Windows isn't good.  My github link https://github.com/crg63/site-web-france.com without call mongo in App.js it's necessary add line to call mongo for view the glitch

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can't use MongoDB NodeJS driver on frontend as you explained. To use it you need a backend server. You code with NodeJS, use MongoDB driver, get the data and with an API endpoint (using server) you serve those data to your frontend.

I'm not sure how does your code work with Windows.

Comment: Ok It's necessary to have 2 distinct applications ? One FrontEnd app who is bind with BackEnd app ?

Comment: Not exactly two distinct application but with one application which has one frontend and one backend code. For backend of course you need a server like `ExpressJS` or any other server application you prefer. With this server you connect to your MongoDB instances using this driver. Then your backend server feeds your frontend.

Comment: But it does not explain why on OSX that works and not witlh Windows. And normally if I call mongodb on js file and I have the node module it's supposed to work ... I will do otherwise. But it's weird anyway that bug

Comment: Unfortunately I can't answer that unless I see your project.